# background Invalid property value in Chrome

Tags: html, css, svg, background, inline

I am getting background `Invalid property value` in Chrome. What am I missing here?

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Email template</title>

</head>
<body style="margin-left: 0; margin-top: 0; margin-right: 0; margin-bottom: 0;">
<div class="t3 sMargin" style="margin-top: 20px; background-color: #dedede; padding-left: 40px; padding-right: 40px; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px;">

    <div class="t31" style="color: #5222a8; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px;">
        Lorem ipsum
    </div>

    <div class="t32" style="background: url( 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,<svg width='100%' height='100%' viewBox='0 0 20 32' version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' preserveAspectRatio='none'><path fill='none' stroke='#be1196' stroke-width='4' d='M4 10 l5 11 l8 -20'/></svg>'); background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat; background-position: 0 0; background-size: 32px 20px; margin-top: 20px; padding-left: 35px; color: #4a4a4a; font-size: 20px;">
        Lorem ipsum
    </div>

    <div class="t32" style="background: url( 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,<svg width='100%' height='100%' viewBox='0 0 20 32' version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' preserveAspectRatio='none'><path fill='none' stroke='#be1196' stroke-width='4' d='M4 10 l5 11 l8 -20'/></svg>'); background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat; background-position: 0 0; background-size: 32px 20px; margin-top: 20px; padding-left: 35px; color: #4a4a4a; font-size: 20px;">
        Lorem ipsum
    </div>

    <div class="t32" style="background: url( 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,<svg width='100%' height='100%' viewBox='0 0 20 32' version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' preserveAspectRatio='none'><path fill='none' stroke='#be1196' stroke-width='4' d='M4 10 l5 11 l8 -20'/></svg>'); background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat; background-position: 0 0; background-size: 32px 20px; margin-top: 20px; padding-left: 35px; color: #4a4a4a; font-size: 20px;">
        Lorem ipsum
    </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Since it is an email template I need my styling to be inlined.

[image]

As you can see no check mark is displayed (I am drawing it with the help of svg in background).

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/76uedo40/707/) is the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to read first this article: [Optimizing SVGs in data URIs](https://codepen.io/tigt/post/optimizing-svgs-in-data-uris). The essence is:
whenever you’re using an SVG as a data URI:

1. Swap its attribute values’ double quotes with single quotes.
2. Encode <, >, #, any remaining " (like in textual content), non-ASCII characters, and other URL-unsafe characters, like %.
3. Wrap the URI with double quotes when using it: , url("").

I hope it helps.

```css
.t32{background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='100%25' height='100%25' viewBox='0 0 20 32' version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' preserveAspectRatio='none'%3E%3Cpath fill='none' stroke='%23be1196' stroke-width='4' d='M4 10 l5 11 l8 -20'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat; 
  background-position: 0 0;  
  background-size: 32px 20px; 
  margin-top: 20px; 
  padding-left: 35px; 
  color: #4a4a4a; 
  font-size: 20px;}
```

```html
<div class="t3 sMargin" style="margin-top: 20px; background-color: #dedede; padding-left: 40px; padding-right: 40px; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px;">

    <div class="t31" style="color: #5222a8; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px;">
        Lorem ipsum
    </div>

    <div class="t32">
        Lorem ipsum
    </div>

    <div class="t32">
        Lorem ipsum
    </div>

    <div class="t32">
        Lorem ipsum
    </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE: this time an example with inline CSS.

Please note that I'm using `&quot;` as a third type of quotes in CSS

```html
<div class="t3 sMargin" style="margin-top: 20px; background-color: #dedede; padding-left: 40px; padding-right: 40px; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px;">

    <div class="t31" style="color: #5222a8; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px;">
        Lorem ipsum
    </div>

    <div class="t32" style="background-image: url(&quot;data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='100%25' height='100%25' viewBox='0 0 20 32' version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' preserveAspectRatio='none'%3E%3Cpath fill='none' stroke='%23be1196' stroke-width='4' d='M4 10 l5 11 l8 -20'/%3E%3C/svg%3E&quot;);background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat; background-position: 0 0; background-size: 32px 20px; margin-top: 20px; padding-left: 35px; color: #4a4a4a; font-size: 20px;">
        Lorem ipsum
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Could you, please, show me the inline version? It does not work as I explained in the question.

Comment: @iamyourfriend I've updated my answer with an example where I'm using inline CSS